# Do you need to use Entity Framework for MVC 4 Single Page Applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've done a bit of research and couldn't find one example where Entity Framework was NOT used in a Single Page App (for MVC 4). Does using SPA require Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does require EF if you mean the SPA concept that has been demonstrated using KnockoutJS and UpshotJS. This is because Upshot is designed to work with the metadata that EF provides.  However, it is early days and we don't know what capabilities Upshot will provide in the future. We may even see client libraries or extensions to Upshot that handle different dbs.

As regards SPA as a concept you can implement this now using ASP.NET MVC, KnockoutJS/BackboneJS and regular JQuery ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

**Single Page Applications (SPAs) definitely do not require ASP.Net MVC.**

SPAs are just an architectural pattern that uses existing web development technologies to create a better user experience.

To see SPAs described in a general way check out this article:
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Since SPAs have become kind of a hot topic in the last couple years, Microsoft chose to provide a way to create SPAs using .NET centric technologies (more than just ASP.Net MVC in fact).

For the Microsoft specific way, take a look at this:
   http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2159

Answer (score -1):

No you don't, that is just MS using it's own technology as much as possible.

For example: GMail from Google is an SPA, admittedly not done using ASP.NET MVC. Do you really think they are using Entity Framework?

Comment: I'm not talking about SPA as a concept. I'm talking about Microsoft's implementation of SPA, specifically. The SPA features coming out from MVC 4 look like they require the use of Entity Framework, and this is what I'm asking about.

Comment: Seems like SPA is on hold at the moment and won't be shipped with MVC 4. :(